# a hint for problem in mathematical analysis

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, metric-spaces

There is a question having several parts. I solved the part (a) but I have problems with other parts.

Let 
$f\in L^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{n}),$
with
$f\geq 0\;$ a.e. 
in 
$\mathbb{R}^{n}$
and let 
$g:\mathbb{R}^{n}\to [0,+\infty)$
be the function defined by 
$$ g(x):=\int_{B(x,\vert x\vert/2)}f(y)dy,$$
where 
$\vert \cdot\vert$ 
denotes the Euclidean norm and 
$B(x,r)=\{y\in \mathbb{R}^{n}:\vert y-x\vert <r\}$
for every 
$x\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$
and every
$r\geq 0.$

(a) Prove that 
$g$ 
is continuous.

(b) Prove that  $g(x)\to 0$
as
$\vert x\vert\to \infty. $

(c) Prove that 
$g$
has a maximum point in 
$\mathbb{R}^{n}.$

Please write only hint and not a whole solution, I have to be accustomed to solve the mathematics problems. A small useful hint will be accepted. Also, if you have seen this problem in other books, please let me know.

Comment: Dominated convergence theorem?

Comment: it does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a) Let $x_n \to x$. Apply the dominated convergence theorem to the sequence $f_n(y) := \mathbb{1}_{B(x_n, |x_n|/2)}(y)f(y)$.

b) Suppose that the assertion weren't true. Then, for some $\epsilon > 0$, there would be a sequence $x_n$ with $|x_n | \to \infty$ such that $g(x_n) > \epsilon$. You may assume wlog that the $B(x_n, |x_n |/2)$ are disjoint. Edit: Because these sets are disjoint, for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we have that

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(y)~\mathrm{d}y \geq \sum_{i=1}^{n}\int_{B(x_i,\vert x_i\vert/2)}f(y)~\mathrm{d}y. $$

c) If $g(x) = 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ the assertion is trivially true. Now let $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be such that $g(y) \neq 0$. By b), there is a $R > 0 $ such that $g(x) < g(y)$ for all $|x| > R$. Consider the restriction of $g$ to $[-R,R]$ and use part $a)$ to conclude.

Comment: thanks for the answer. 
I had solved a like you.
for the c you hint is very useful. 
But for the b I couldn't do more...

Comment: @HamedBaghalGhaffari I expanded the hint for b) a little more.

Answer (score 2):

b.  Let $|x_k|\to \infty.$ Then $\chi_{B(x_k,|x_k|/2)} \to 0$ pointwise everywhere. Hence so does $f\cdot\chi_{B(x_k,|x_k|/2)}.$ Since $f\cdot\chi_{B(x_k,|x_k|/2)}\le f $ everywhere, the dominated convergence theorem shows $g(x_k)\to 0.$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I thought your method to solve (b) by myself already, but my problem was the first part. Could you tell me how could you conclude that 
$\chi_{B(x_{k},\vert x_{k}\vert/2)}\to 0?$

Comment: @HamedBaghalGhaffari For any $y,$ we have $y\notin B(x/|x|/2)$ as soon as $|y|<|x|/2.$

Comment: thank you so much. I did it.